# Why the number of ways of selecting $r$ things out of $n$ identical things is 1

Tags: combinatorics

Would some one please provide me a detailed information regarding -
"why the number of ways selecting $r$ things out of $n$ identical things is 1".

Here is my example - let's say I entered into clothes shop and I saw a set of 100 identical shirts. So if I have to select any 5 out of these 100, I can select them in 
even series or odd series or multiples of 10 series or first 5 or last 5 or randomly any 5 right? then why every where I am seeing just "1" as answer.

Comment: *Where* do you see 1 as an answer? It seems rather odd to me.

Comment: @Harald: It’s not clear, but I suspect that what’s meant is that if the shirts are truly indistinguishable, you can’t tell one set of $5$ from another, so there is only one **distinguishable** set of $5$ shirts.

Comment: The idea is that no matter how you select them you still end up with 5 identical shirts... So you basically chose them in a different way, but your choice is always the same: 5 shirts which are the same no matter how you chose them.... More or less is not 1 choice, there are actually multiple choices, but no matter what choice you make it is only one possible outcome....

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it should really be about picking 5 out of 100 *electrons*, then. Now I understand.

Comment: @NS But the question is not about how many possible outcomes right? ,the statement clearly asking us number of ways

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Jp51spL2JOoC&pg=SA4-PA38&lpg=SA4-PA38&dq=selecting+r+things+out+of+n+identical+things&source=bl&ots=dqwD3yqM9e&sig=ZJBcHefB6o-rfJWNq1MJzBf2Jpc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ULozUY74Eo3wrQfFzICoDg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=selecting%20r%20things%20out%20of%20n%20identical%20things&f=false

Answer (score 2):

If you have five objects $A,B,C,D$ and $E$, then the number of ways of choosing $r,1\le r\le 5$ objects out of these five is $n \choose r$. But if the five are identical and are $A,A,A,A$ and $A$, then there is no "way" to choose. If you need 2 objects, the choice is AA; if you need three, the choice is AAA and so on.

So there is just "one way" or one choice when the objects are identical.

Answer (score 2):

That is because however you chose, since they are **all identical**, you can not precisely say that the one you have was not the one you didn't chose from the given sample.

Consider it like this:

You have 3 trucks full of sand and you want to select 5 kg from it. Now, it doesn't matter how many times you take it out, how much quantity you take out with each turn as long as you, at the end, have just 5 kg of sand with you.

On the other hand, if I'm to have other constrains on the same example, such as first truck can not provide more than 1 kg, you must take at least 3 kg from 2nd and so on, the calculations would change.

Similarly, in your example, you're constraining your selection based on their positions in the shop. While, no such thing is mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The shirts are identical, meaning that no matter if you selected shirts number 1,2,3,4,5 or 5,10,15,20,25, the result will be the same: You have 5 idendical shirts and the shop has 95 identical shirts.

Comment: Even though the result is same .The way we chose is different right.So would you please explain me . what is the exact meaning of  different ways ?

Comment: Yes, there is some linguistic hairsplitting going on here. My impression is that you are looking for a justification for the answer "1". And a possible justification is "different ways" means "different outcomes". But you are right: With a slightly different interpretation of "different ways", the answer could very well also be $\binom{100}{5}$.