# Sample space for identical objects

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Sample space for a set of balls in an urn out of which say $p$ are of blue color (hence identical), $q$ are of red color is written as a multiset and not as a set, or rather when it is written as a set the identical objects are written as different objects in the following way:-

$\text{Set representation} - \{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_p,r_1, r_2,\ldots,r_q\}\\
\text{Multiset representation}-\{b,b,\ldots\text{p times}, r,r,\ldots\text{q times}\}$

And based on the above sample space if we are asked to find the probability of selecting a blue ball we get it as $\dfrac{p}{p+q}$, which was found using the [classical definition of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_definition_of_probability). According to the classical definition of probability, probability of an event $E$ as given as 
$$P(E)=\dfrac{n(E)}{n(S)}$$

Now why is that the ways of selecting $r$(here, $r=1$) things out of $n$ identical things is ${n}\choose{r}$ and not $1$ as is the case [in combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319814/why-the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-r-things-out-of-n-identical-things-is-1).

---

**Edit 1:-**

To further clarify my point consider these two contrasting cases below:-

**Case 1:-**

Consider an urn in which there are $30$ distinct balls out of which there are $10$ distinct blue balls and $20$ distinct white balls. Let's say the distinction b/w the balls of identical color is made by marking them with numbers which cant be felt by the one drawing the ball. Now in a random draw if we are asked the probability of picking a blue ball, then according to the classical definition of probability it will be $\dfrac{10}{30}=\dfrac{1}{3}$.

We had arrived the above probability because we know that 
$$n(E:\text{drawing a blue ball})={{10}\choose{1}}=10\\
n(S:\text{drawing a ball from the earn})={{30}\choose{1}}=30$$

Just listing the sets $E$(event space) and $S$(sample space) for comparing these with the next case.

$E=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,\ldots,B_{10}\}\\
S=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,\ldots,B_{10},W_1,W_2,W_3,\ldots, W_{20}\}$

**Case 2:-**

The  setting for this case is the same as the previous case the only difference is that that the balls of same color are indistinguishable. So, if we are asked the probability of drawing a blue ball the probability would come out as $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

My thinking behind this probability is that the sample space for this random draw would be $$S=\{W,B\}$$ as all the white balls are identical to each other and so are all the blue balls. Similarly, the event space would be $$E=\{B\}$$ as all the blue balls are identical.

But by this logic the probability of drawing a blue ball would still be $\dfrac{1}{2}$, when the blue balls are present in a vast quantity as compared to the white balls which would be other than the expected result.

So, my question again boils down to the same one as in the pre edit part of the post, i.e.

> Why do we use the multi-set representation for identical objects or while writing it in set notation why do we consider the identical objects as distinct objects?

Comment: For more variations, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P(E)=\dfrac{n(E)}{n(S)}$$ if and only if all the simple outcomes in the sample space have the same probability.

The balls may be indistinguishable, but there are more white than blue balls so there's more chance you'll select white than blue. In other words, the two simple outcomes in the sample space $S=\{W,B\}$ have different probabilities, violating the above condition.

Another classic example is flip two coins. One sample space would give the number of heads. $$S_2=\{0,1,2\}$$ However, you can't use it to find the probability of $0$ heads, you'll get $\frac 13$ instead of $\frac 1 4$. The sample space $$S_3=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$$ has equiprobable sample points so it can be used.

Comment: So, each component in the proper(or rather correct) sample space is ${1}\over{n}$th part of the whole, given that there are n components in the sample space(disregarding distinguishability). So, if the probability of choosing any object from the sample space is $\dfrac{1}{n}$, then what would be the probability of choosing a particular blue colored ball from the urn if all the blue balls are indistinguishable(in case-2 in my edit)

Comment: You need to be very clear what your sample space means. What does $B$ in $S=\{W,B\}$ mean? It means pick *any* blue ball, which is not useful when answering the question 'What's the probability of picking a particular blue ball.' For the experiment of picking a card from a standard deck, the sample space $S_4=\{B,R\}$, meaning pick a black or red card, is fine, but not useful in answering the question 'what's the probability of a red king?'

Comment: So if in the sample space $S=\{W,B\}$ $B$ represents choosing any blue ball, then what would $B$ represent in the multiset $S=\{B,B,B,\ldots,10\text{times},W,W,\ldots,\text{20 times}\}$. I think that it still represents choosing any blue ball $B$ but since the balls are not distinguishable then it still doesn't hold any meaning for the question "What's the probability of picking a particular blue ball." Am I correct. So the question of the particular ball had made sense only when some particular blue bol had been distinguished in some way from the others.

Comment: By saying 'particular ball' you are distinguishing it. Your example is a good example of how things work. If there are 20 white and 10 blue balls, it's completely counter intuitive to say that the probability of picking a blue ball with one random choice is $\frac 1 2$. In fact, if there are 10 blue balls and a million white ones, the same reasoning would still lead to a probability of $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: This might look a little strange but how does my example tell "how things work". I am just asking so that I can learn what relates my example to the real world.

Comment: Also, now that the issue of sample space is resolved, I have another doubt regarding the number of instances favouring the occurrence of the event "choosing a blue ball in a random draw". From all the discussion till now I understand that the number of instances favouring the event is $10$ since there are 10 blue balls so the probability is ${1}\over{3}$. But from a combinatorial point of view the number of ways of choosing a blue ball from 10 identical Blue Balls is 1, i.e. just choosing a blue ball. So the probability should be 1/30. Where is my reasoning wrong in the second case.

Comment: Look at the number 1/30. What does the 1 represent? What does the 30 represent? When you say 'the probability should be 1/30,' what probability do you mean? If you mean the probability of picking a blue ball, then there are 10 ways to choose a blue ball out of 30 total ways to choose any type of ball.If  you mean the probability of picking one specific blue ball, then there is 1 way to choose that specific blue ball out of 30 ways to choose any type of ball.

Comment: I think I understand why the way of counting event space and sample space for identical objects in probability is different from that in combinatorics. In Probability, we don't know for sure whether what we want is going to be the outcome of the experiment or not. Hence, we consider the identical objects as different and then prepare the sample space, and for the event related to the identical objects to occur, in this case blue ball, if any of the blue ball is drawn then the event is said to have occurred. Part(1/2)

Comment: Part(2/2) So the combinatorial way of counting the instances for the occurrence of the blue ball doesn't work here since we are not certain of picking the ball surely in any trial, that's why each blue ball represents an additional count to the occurrence of the event of drawing a blue ball. Is my reasoning right.

Comment: I think you're getting in trouble with your language. "The combinatorial way of counting" is not a useful way to think of things, in my opinion. One basic idea of probability, in words, is the probability of something happening is the number of ways it can happen divided by how many total things can occur if each thing that can occur has the same probability. So you must count both how many things total can occur and how many ways the event can occur. You can use some tools from combinatorics to count those two things if you want, but you must count correctly.

Comment: Hmm....now that I think I was too focused on the way of counting things combinatrioally(I hope that word exists) and that was the root cause for all the doubts that I had. Thank you for sparing so much time for me.