# Selection of r objects out of n identical objects.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know this is a duplicate, but other questions (and their answers) are not satisfying my doubt regarding this questions. Is there no effect of the objects being identical or not, when selection is involved? Shouldn't it be one?

Please stick to this example: A bag contains 12 red balls and 6 white balls. Six balls are drawn one by one without replacement. So I want to calculate the ways in which 3 red balls and 3 white balls can be selected.

Other similar questions may be found here, but I am not able to clear my doubts by them:

[Selection from identical objects - distinction between number of ways and number of outcomes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/779243/200662)

[Why the number of ways of selecting $r$ things out of $n$ identical things is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319814/200662)

Comment: it's the *hypergeometric distribution*.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Please elaborate. I have no clue what a hypergeometric distribution is.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan the hypergeometric distribution is just the probability of $a$ successes after $n$ draws without replacement, which is essentially your problem. Look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDistribution.html)

Comment: @RajivKaipa Thanks. So should I memorise this case as a rule of thumb?
 Because the hypergeometric distribution is a completely new term to me, and I have studied only what is prescribed in the IIT JEE 2017 syllabus.

Comment: It depends on the problem you are doing. If you only care about the number of each colour drawn then, of course there is only 1 outcome of 3 white and 3 red. But if you are calculating a probability for a real bag of balls you must consider balls as distinct because in real life they are made distinct by the virtue that any two balls of the same colour are not the **same ball**, in this case we treat balls as if they are labeled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "ways". If you are thinking of the number of possible histories then we have to count the number of words of length $6$ over the alphabet $\{R,W\}$ containing three $R$s and three $W$s. This number is ${6\choose3}=20$. As long as there are at least three of each in the bag the initial number of balls in the bag is irrelevant.

I guess you expected a different answer. So please define clearly what you mean by "ways".